# an image that breaks through its div container, over the menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image, responsive-design

I am trying to generate a page that displays an image based on the screen's proportions

I am using bootstrap, and specific css to define the images as: responsive and rotating, based on the aspect ratio

When the image is rotated vertically, its not "being contained" in its div container, and is displayed over the menu

I would like to keep the same image behavior, that is to keep it responsive and in the container, regardless of the fact that it is rotating based on the aspect ratio

Below is the relevant sample code (I didn't bother adding the full menu), I also have a running [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qwypszr8/) example

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/vbfqy.css'>

<style>
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 1/1) {
  .propor {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}
</style>


        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" target="_blank">Brand</a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <!-- li><a href="#">Link</a></li -->
                <li class="dropdown">123</li></ul></div></nav>


<div class="container-fluid" >

    <img class="img-responsive propor" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=600%C3%97350&w=600&h=350">

</div>


  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS below will rotate the image and keep it within the container whilst being responsive.

Divide the image width on the image height to get the aspect ratio needed for this transformation to work correctly. 
600/350 = 171.42

```
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 1/1) {
  .propor {
    transform: rotate(90deg) translate3d(0,-171.42%,0) scale(1.7142);
    transform-origin: top left;
  }
}
```

Comment: sounds very interesting, and like what I need. I'll check that!

Comment: If my image my changes to another in a scale of 1.5 to 1.8, how would I need to update the code?

Comment: If your image size changes you divide the image width on the image height to get an aspect ratio. Example with a 600x330px image. 600/330 = 1.818. Plug this ratio into the `scale(1.818)`, then move the comma back two spaces and plug the number in as a negative percentage amount in the y position of the `translate3d(0,-181.8%,0)`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try!

Answer (score 1):

Need to set margin-top for aspect ratio design:

```
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 1/1)
.propor {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    margin-top: 55px;/*Newly added*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks! works. why specifically 55px ? seems a bit arbitrary... is there a more generic parameter to add ?

Comment: actually you need to add header height to margin-top

Comment: Based on a predefined value (55, 57, or 59px) or is it possible to tell the css what it is dynamically ?

Comment: yes it is possible dynamically but you need javascript or jquery for this for now you can set margin-top:70px;

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to rotate the image around the left bottom corner. This sets the image down by 100% of the height; it then translates it for your required affect.

```
.propor {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%) rotate(90deg); /* Safari */
    -moz-transform: translateY(-100%) rotate(90deg); /* Firefox 3.6 Firefox 4 */
    /*-moz-transform-origin: right top; */
    -ms-transform: translateY(-100%) rotate(90deg); /* IE9 */
    -o-transform: translateY(-100%) rotate(90deg); /* Opera */
    transform: translateY(-100%) rotate(90deg); /* W3C */  
    -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -moz-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -ms-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -o-transform-origin: left bottom;
    transform-origin: left bottom;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would like it centered also

Answer (score 0):

Although the image is tipped vertically, the img-responsive class is being applied to it as if it was horizontally placed. So even if you apply margins upon being rotated vertically, the result wouldn't be neat/perfect.

May i suggest that you keep a separate (Portrait) image (and not transform this one on the aspect ratio 1:1)... that way the img-responsive class can behave predictably and you get what you wanted all along.

Comment: That is an issue, since the images would change from view to view, and I would't want to double my image library...

Comment: this is how bootstrap is... best to let it do what it is good at. Adding arbitary margins (via jQuery for e.g.) would entail a lot of processing work and the result will never be perfect or neat... if you want pixel perfect reliability, you would have to double your images or crop them if your business requirement allows you to...